# Loading multiple image URLs to 4D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I have around 300 Images which I am fetching from Image URL. Each Image (RGB) is 256x256x3. I want a numpy array that I can feed into CNN model of shape = (300,256,256,3). How to do this in Python?

This code below is giving me error

```
X_data = np.array([])
print('Iterating across ',len(df_train),' rows')
for index,row in tqdm_notebook(df_train.iterrows()):
    img = {}
    try:
        img = img_to_array(load_img(BytesIO(requests.get(row['IMAGE_URL_1']).content), target_size=(256, 256)))
        X_data.append(img)
    except Exception:
        print('Error in Fetching Image_URL_1 = ',row['IMAGE_URL_1'],' lot = ',row['LOT_NUMBER'])
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the Pillow library for reading the image data from URL content. [Here's](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/NYuVzCsOVb) is a simple example.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import requests

X_data = []
print('Iterating across ',len(df_train),' rows')
for index,row in tqdm_notebook(df_train.iterrows()):
    try:
        # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(row['IMAGE_URL_1']).content)).resize((256, 256), PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
        X_data.append(np.array(img))
    except Exception:
        print('Error in Fetching Image_URL_1 = ',row['IMAGE_URL_1'],' lot = ',row['LOT_NUMBER'])
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay235.  But X_data becomes a list in this code you shared. I want a 4d np.array

Comment: @DebayanMitra, consider upvoting the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: After the Code of **Sanjay** you need to convert the list to an array.

You do this by simply writing `X_data_4D=np.stack(X_data, axis=0)` after the for-loop.

Like that, you will convert a list of (256,256,3) images to one (300,256,256,3) array.